# У background есть параметры?

Tags: android

Как добраться к настройкам background элементов TextView? Есть ли аналоги из CSS: background-position, background-repeat, background-size ?

Answer (score 1):

Программно поменять что-то в фоне нельзя, только заменить его на к-л другой цвет/файл-картинку.

Но можно сделать фон через `xml` и вот там уже можно настроить некоторые вещи. Вот пример, который можно назначить в виде фона вьюхе. Тут картинка будет повторяться

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/SOME_IMAGE_FILE_IN_DRAWABLE_FOLDER"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```